# How to maven release:prepare issue and Plugin not found issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

Hello I am following along a Spring course and am currently trying to do multi-module maven builds. Most of it is working however it is sating my maven-release-plugin cannot be found. As well as this when i run release:prepare I am getting this error:

[Maven Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY6H4.png)

I am completely lost on ways to solve it, I have tried to delete and reimport the plugins. invalidate the cache and restart yet I cannot solve it. Any help would be great.

If you need any more code please let me know

Comment: You need to commit to your git/svn first.

Comment: Hi thanks this is what it was in the end, redownloaded my version and then did it all again

Answer (score 0):

You can only run the Maven release plugin if you commit your changes first.